# Can't get warnings for unused functions

Tags: swift, xcode

I'd like Xcode to show a warning if I have unused functions in my project. I'm using Swift.

I went to `Project / Build settings` and in section `Apple LLVM 8.1 - Warnings - All Languages` I've set `Unused functions` to `Yes`.

[image]

But I'm not getting any warning for unused functions in my project.

How can I set Xcode correctly to show me warnings for unused functions?

Comment: File an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: You might want to look at SwiftLint: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint which is a configurable tool for better Code style. Not sure, if SwiftLint comes with highlighting unused methods by default, but if not, you can just setup a rule for that. Let me know, if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that any of those warning flags apply to Swift; they mostly apply to the C-based languages (C, C++, Objective-C). My understanding is that the Swift team wants to avoid creating "dialects" of the language, so all the warnings and errors that the Swift compiler supports are always on, and there aren't really ways to turn individual warnings on or off. So given that, my supposition is that the Swift compiler doesn't currently have any way to check for unused functions.